# Can we invoke apk file in button click method?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Launch an application from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

I have created login android application. We have a calendar.apk file and now we want to invoke this file when login button is clicked. How can we do that? Can you please provide us a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for Launching .apk file programmatically. You need to use Intents. [Launch Application through your code](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98android.amberfog.com/?p=98).