# Can we invoke apk file in button click method?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we invoke apk file in button click method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504848/can-we-invoke-apk-file-in-button-click-method)

Thanks for your response. I have the calendar application source code and I executed it successfully. Now in my login application once the user clicks login button the calendar application should open. Could you please suggest any code for this in android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See: [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

Comment: Asker has changed his question in response to answers/comments.

Comment: @Madhuri: Follow the links to the duplicate questions, they contain source examples